# how to send value from grid (pop up) to form panel in extjs

Tags: extjs

how to show data in form panel after click one of data in pop up in grid view, I have try another way but always wrong,
this is my grid panel :

```
var tt = Ext.define('Rendering.view.beli.dataSupplier', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
//extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
//  xtype: 'beligrid',

alias : 'widget.contatoform',

frame: true,
// id: 'detailPanelis',
title: 'Company data',
bodyPadding: 5,
layout: 'column',
requires: [
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.layout.container.Column'
],

initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            columnWidth: 0.65,
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            reference: 'customerGrid',
            store: 'BeliStore',
            columns : [{
                text: 'Nama',
                dataIndex: 'namaSupplier',
                flex: 1

            }, {
                text: 'Alamat',
                dataIndex: 'address',
                flex: 1

            }],
            listeners: {


                scope: this,
                selectionchange: 'onSelectionChanges'
            }


        }];
    //];
    // });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onSelectionChanges: function(model, records) {
        //alert('yuhuuuu');
    var editt = Ext.create('Rendering.view.beli.bg_beli');

    var c =  editt.onSelectionChange(model, records);

}

 });
```

the function for to send data to form panel is

```
listeners: {
              scope: this,
                selectionchange: 'onSelectionChanges'
            }
```

this is function of onSelectionChanges :

```
 onSelectionChanges: function(model, records) {
        //alert('yuhuuuu');
    var editt = Ext.create('Rendering.view.beli.bg_beli');

    var c =  editt.onSelectionChange(model, records);

  }
```

and form panel :

```
var tt = Ext.define('Rendering.view.beli.bg_beli', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

xtype: 'beligrid',

controller: 'binding-dynamic',
frame: true,

title: 'Company data',
bodyPadding: 5,
layout: 'column',



requires: [
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.layout.container.Column'
],

// In this example, configuration is applied at initComponent time
// because it depends on profileInfo object that is generated for the
// FormGrid instance.
initComponent: function() {
    //Ext.apply(this, {


    this.items = [
        {
            columnWidth: 0.65,
            xtype: 'gridpanel',

            store: 'BeliStore',
            columns : [{
                text: 'Nama',
                dataIndex: 'namaSupplier',
                flex: 1

            }, {
                text: 'Alamat',
                dataIndex: 'address',
                flex: 1

            }],
            listeners: {

                scope: this,
                selectionchange: 'onSelectionChange'
            }


        },{
            columnWidth: 0.35,
            margin: '20 0 0 10',
            xtype: 'form',
            title:'Company detailsss',
            layout: 'anchor',

            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [
            {

                name : 'id_supplier',
                fieldLabel: 'id',
                hidden:true
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Nama Supplier',
                name: 'namaSupplier'

            },{
                    fieldLabel: 'email',
                    name: 'email'

            },{
                    fieldLabel: 'alamat',
                    name: 'address'

            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'YUY',
                action: 'add'
            }]

        }];
    //];
   // });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onSelectionChange: function(model, records) {

    alert('asdasd');


    console.log(records);
    var rec = records[0];
    console.log(rec);
    if (rec) {
       var c = this.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
     //   this.getBeliStoreStore().load();
        console.log(this.getForm().loadRecord(rec));
    }
}

});
```

I send data from grid to form panel, and the function that accepted data in form panel is :

```
 onSelectionChange: function(model, records) {

    alert('asdasd');


    console.log(records);
    var rec = records[0];
    console.log(rec);
    if (rec) {
       var c = this.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
     //   this.getBeliStoreStore().load();
        console.log(this.getForm().loadRecord(rec));
    }
}
```

please help, I have looking for to any reference but I don't get answer yet, thanks before

Comment: What kind of error are you getting in the console? Or is just that you can't see the row data in the form when you select it in the grid? and also, ¿version of ExtJS?

Comment: there is no error in console, but in console form panel (parent) data has accepted but in form cannot show the data

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is modify the call for event this.onSelectionChange or like that this.on('selectionchange',this.onSelectionChange) it is another way for call events in extjs

```
initComponent: function() {

    var me = this ;

    this.items = [
        {
            columnWidth: 0.65,
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            reference: 'customerGrid',
            store: 'BeliStore',
            columns : [{
                text: 'Nama',
                dataIndex: 'namaSupplier',
                flex: 1

            }, {
                text: 'Alamat',
                dataIndex: 'address',
                flex: 1

            }],
            listeners: {    
                scope: this,
                selectionchange: me.onSelectionChanges
            }


        }];
    //];
    // });
    this.callParent(arguments);
}

OR

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this ;

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                     reference: 'customerGrid',
                     store: 'BeliStore',
                     columns : [{
                         text: 'Nama',
                         dataIndex: 'namaSupplier',
                         flex: 1

                      }, {
                         text: 'Alamat',
                         dataIndex: 'address',
                         flex: 1   
                     }
                    ]});

    me.items = [
        {
            columnWidth: 0.65,
            grid               

        }];       

    grid.on('selectionchange',me.onSelectionChange)

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#form-grid

Comment: this.on('selectionchange',this.onSelectionChange) is function in form panel but error, because no function pass in that method, if I change to  var edit = Ext.create('Rendering.view.beli.bg_beli');
        edit.on('selectionchange',edit.onSelectionChange), the function can pass, and accepted in form panel(parent) but can't show data in form panel..

Comment: hi , just add one alias for you hoot element, like "me" and add the reference for you function, check I've modified the first suggestion